# Trouble with Subobject Navigation in OData API Configuration

Tags: c#, swagger, odata

I'm working on configuring an OData API using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData, and I'm facing challenges with setting up navigation for sub-objects. Specifically, I have entities with sub-objects (e.g., project 5 with budget and in that sub-object I have the sub-objects costs, hours2, total), and I'm struggling to configure the relationships and navigation properly, and it needs to work because I need that information in power BI but when I try to expand records or tables it says this error:

> DataSource.NotFound: OData: Request failed (404): The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
> Details:
> DataSourceKind=OData
> DataSourcePath=https://localhost:7028/api/Expense('expense%3A6449fae7e07a897cb1c01766409047e3')/default_costtype
> Url=https://localhost:7028/api/Expense('expense:6449fae7e07a897cb1c01766409047e3')/default_costtype

This is my program.cs

```cs
// Hier wordt Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData gebruikt, dit is een bibliotheek voor het bouwen van OData API's.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
// Hier worden verschillende namespaces geïmporteerd voor het bouwen van de OData API.
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;
using ODataService.api.Services;
using ODataService.api.Models;
using ODataService.Api.Models;



// Een builder object wordt gemaakt om de applicatie te configureren.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Services worden toegevoegd aan de container, dit zijn onderdelen die de applicatie functionaliteit bieden.
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>
    options.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("api", GetEdmModel()));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApiService>();
builder.Services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConsole(); // You can replace this with other providers if needed
});
// De applicatie wordt gebouwd met de geconfigureerde services.
var app = builder.Build();

// Als de applicatie draait in een ontwikkelingsomgeving, worden Swagger documentatie en UI toegevoegd.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// HTTPS-omleiding wordt ingeschakeld en autorisatie wordt geconfigureerd.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

// De controllers van de applicatie worden gemapt.
app.MapControllers();

// De applicatie wordt gestart en blijft draaien.
app.Run();

// Een functie om het Edm-model voor de OData API te maken.
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    // Een builder object wordt gemaakt om het model te configureren.
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();



    builder.EntitySet<CostsType>("CostsType").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.id).Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

    builder.EntitySet<Expense>("Expense").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Id).Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

    builder.EntitySet<ProjectAssignment>("ProjectAssignment").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.id).Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

    builder.EntitySet<ProjectService>("ProjectService").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.id).Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

    builder.EntitySet<Project5>("Project").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.id).Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

    builder.EntitySet<Hours>("Hours").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.id).Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

    builder.EntitySet<HoursType>("HoursType").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.id).Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();

    builder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("WeatherForecast").EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select();


    // Het uiteindelijke Edm-model wordt opgehaald en teruggegeven.
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

and this is one of the classes if you need it

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

 

namespace ODataService.api.Models

{

    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);

    public class Budget

    {

        public Costs? costs { get; set; }

        public Hours2? hours { get; set; }

        public Total? total { get; set; }

    }



    public class Costs

    {

        public int? value_budget { get; set; }

        public double? value_spent { get; set; }

    }



    public class CustomField

    {

        public CustomFieldGroup? custom_field_group { get; set; }

        public bool? filterable { get; set; }

        public string? id { get; set; }

        public string? label { get; set; }

        public bool? mandatory { get; set; }

        public string? name { get; set; }

        public List<Option>? options { get; set; }

        public int? position { get; set; }

        public string? render_type { get; set; }

        public bool? searchable { get; set; }

        public string? value_type { get; set; }
        public Project5 Project { get; set; }

    }



    public class CustomFieldGroup

    {

        public string? id { get; set; }

        public string? name { get; set; }

        public string? position { get; set; }



    }



    public class Project5

    {

        public bool? billable { get; set; }

        public Budget? budget { get; set; }

        public bool? can_register_mileage { get; set; }

        public string? created { get; set; }

        public string? created_at { get; set; }

        public List<CustomField>? custom_fields { get; set; }

        public string? hours_rate_type { get; set; }

        public string? id { get; set; }

        public bool? is_invoice_approval { get; set; }

        public bool? is_reverse_billing { get; set; }

        public string? modified { get; set; }

        public MyOrganizationProfile? my_organization_profile { get; set; }

        public string? my_organization_profile_id { get; set; }

        public string? name { get; set; }

        public Organization3? organization { get; set; }

        public string? organization_id { get; set; }

        public ProjectStatus? project_status { get; set; }

        public SeparateInvoiceRecipient? separate_invoice_recipient { get; set; }

        public string? simplicate_url { get; set; }

        public string? timeline_email_address { get; set; }

        public string? updated_at { get; set; }

        public string? end_date { get; set; }

        public Person? person { get; set; }

        public string? person_id { get; set; }

        public ProjectManager? project_manager { get; set; }

        public string? start_date { get; set; }

        public string? project_number { get; set; }

    }



    public class Hours2

    {

        public int? amount_budget { get; set; }

        public double? amount_spent { get; set; }

        public double? value_spent { get; set; }

        public double? value_budget { get; set; }

    }



    public class MyOrganizationProfile

    {

        public string? id { get; set; }

        public Organization? organization { get; set; }

    }



    public class Option

    {

        public string? label { get; set; }

        public string? value { get; set; }

    }



    public class Organization3

    {

        public string? id { get; set; }

        public string? name { get; set; }

    }



    public class Person

    {

        public string? full_name { get; set; }

        public string? id { get; set; }

    }



    public class ProjectManager

    {

        public string? employee_id { get; set; }

        public string? id { get; set; }

        public string? name { get; set; }

        public string? person_id { get; set; }

    }



    public class ProjectStatus

    {

        public string? id { get; set; }

        public string? label { get; set; }

    }



    public class ProjectRoot

    {

        public List<Project5>? data { get; set; }

        public object? debug { get; set; }

        public object? errors { get; set; }

    }



    public class SeparateInvoiceRecipient

    {

        public bool? is_separate_invoice_recipient { get; set; }

    }



    public class Total

    {

        public double? value_budget { get; set; }

        public double? value_invoiced { get; set; }

        public double? value_spent { get; set; }

    }

}
```

How can I correctly configure sub-object navigation for entities in an OData API using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData? Are there specific methods or configurations I'm missing, considering that this is my first experience with C# and OData API? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I expect to configure sub object navigation for entities in an OData API successfully. The ultimate goal is to seamlessly integrate this data with Power BI first time.